# Blender lighting effect with smoke

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

Just wondering if anyone knew how to achieve the exact lighting effect as in this video (in particular the "dust" particles floating in the area and the flashing of light)?  I'm not too interested in how the actual smoke was created.  Video can be found below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVq6HJy49Rc

### My attempt:

[image: Example 1]
It's just a particle system with the following node setup and particle settings.  I also tweaked the camera to have an aperture of radius 0.5

### Node setup:

[image: Example 2]

### Particle settings:

[image: Example 3]

### What I'm trying to achieve:

1. Notice the bright flash of light just to the left of the smoke.  Notice the smoothness, subtle colour gradient and only lights up part of the scene.  This is what I want to achieve.  It also really adds definition to the smoke, normally when I add a standard light (plane with emission shader) all it does it make things brighter which looks very average.
   [image: Example 4]
2. Flash of light is halfway between really bright and none at all (easier to see in the video).  There looks to be a subtle rainbow colour to some of the particles on the left sort of like a lensing effect and are more irregular in shape which is quite good.  I want to achieve all of this also.
   [image: Example 5]
3. Flash of light is gone, mainly just showing this to contrast the different stages of the lighting effect.  Smoke is still quite well defined in terms of lighting.
   [image: Example 6]

Comment: While videos are a welcome complement to a question they should not be the only source of information. Please edit your question and thouroughly describe what you want to achieve, possibly accompanied by some reference images. Also show what you have tried so far

Comment: The *flash light* is called [lens flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare), it's a post effect. Basically just another layer on top of the rendering to give it more depth. Easiest way is using some real footage and "overlay" that with the [mix node of the compositor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/mix.html).

Comment: Thanks brockmann, Does this post effect stuff light up other objects in the scene?  Don’t suppose you would be able to provide an example of how it’s done?